# How to remove padding from content dialog?

Tags: uwp

How to remove the padding/margin in ContentDialog? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604321/remove-space-that-the-primary-and-secondary-buttons-are-holding-on-a-contentdial) or other did not help me. I tried with padding & margin in both ContentDialog's tag and Root Grid as below.

```
<ContentDialog...  Padding="0" Margin="0">

<Grid Background="Bisque" Width="500" Height="400" Padding="0" Margin="0">            
<Button Content="X" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
</Grid>
```

with no luck. But, In Live Visual Tree, I found a Grid(DialogSpace) occupying this area. But how to access and modify it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In these situations the first step should always be to go look for the *generic.xaml* file, which is responsible for defining the template of the several controls.

Taking a look onto the file defined for the *10.0.16299* build (**Fall Creators Update**), I could find the following resource defined:

```
<Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">24,18,24,24</Thickness>
```

Which is later being referenced on a `Grid`, named *DialogSpace* (as you have correctly identified), during the definition of the `ContentDialog`'s template.

```
<Grid x:Name="DialogSpace" Padding="{ThemeResource ContentDialogPadding}">
```

- **The easiest option to fix this issue, is for you to define your own `Thickness` resource in your project with the same Key identifier**,
  where you override the values, *24,18,24,24*, to something that
  better fits your intentions.

You can override this resource in a place where the scope is the entire application, by implementing it on the *App.xaml*. But imagining that your application only has a single `ContentDialog` or you only desire to do this at one place, it would make perfect sense to define this at a lower scoped place, like at the `ContentDialog` resource level, like this:

```
<ContentDialog ...>
    <ContentDialog.Resources>
       <Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>
    </ContentDialog.Resources>
     ....
</ContentDialog>
```

- The second option would consist in "importing" the template into the project, and simply remove the reference to the *ContentDialogPadding* resource by the `Padding` dependency property of the *DialogScope* Grid. 
  But these templates are obviously really big, and for such a small modification, it does not seem like the appropriate option.

The location of the generic.xaml file is the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\{build version}\Generic
```