# How to remove content padding from content dialog on Android Uno platform?

Tags: android, uwp, uno-platform

[Uwp image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBuFy.png)

[Android image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKdv.jpg)

I have tried setting `<Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>` solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665277/how-to-remove-padding-from-content-dialog). It works on [Uwp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBuFy.png) but not on [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKdv.jpg).

Comment: [Show us what you tried](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), and [explain what “it does not work” means](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: I create this resource  `<Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>` which works well on UWP but not on Android. Have a look at these images (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBuFy.png) , (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKdv.jpg).

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks for the help in clarifying. It would be useful for the question being asked to leave some time before closing the question. I understand the question and I can answer it.

Comment: @Jerome Laban reopened now

Answer (score 1):

This icompatibility has already been fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/1766) in case the problem still occurs you have to overide the content dialog's style https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/1f1b8c9f136f84b9160c8470eb49d00f489985e4/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Controls/ContentDialog/ContentDialog.xaml#L24 and set ContentDialogPadding accordingly. Thank you @Jerome Leban for helping.